# Add a letter after the paragraph heading

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

I've currently set the `\paragraph` command to function like "subsubsubsection". But I would like to add a letter "a" after each `\paragraph` numbering. I am not familiar with all the commands in LaTeX. How can I modify the existing command to achieve this? Currently, I use

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

And each paragraph heading looks like

[image]

But I would like to add an "a" after the number, so I would like to change the numbering to look like **5.2.1.1.a** instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the numbering to the following:

```
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}.a}
```